# Prime finite field (Z/pZ) in Haskell with Operator Overloading

Tags: haskell, operator-overloading

I have some code right now that creates a prime field of order n, with all the necessary functions to compute addition, multiplication, and their inverses. It works fine, but I really want to be able to overload the Integral and Num infix functions of +, -, *, /, and ^, but I don't know how to do this. Here's my current code:

```
import Data.Maybe

data FiniteField = FiniteField {add::(FieldElement -> FieldElement -> FieldElement),
              addinv::(FieldElement -> FieldElement),
              mul::(FieldElement -> FieldElement -> FieldElement),
              mulinv::(FieldElement -> FieldElement),
              new::(Integer -> FieldElement)
              }

newtype FieldElement = FieldElement Integer deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

toInt :: FieldElement -> Integer
toInt (FieldElement x) = x

gcdExt :: Integer -> Integer -> (Integer, Integer, Integer)
gcdExt a 0 = (1, 0, a)
gcdExt a b = (t, s - q * t, g)
    where (q, r) = quotRem a b
          (s, t, g) = gcdExt b r

modMulInv :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
modMulInv a n = i
    where (i, _, _) = gcdExt a n

isPrimeLoop :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
isPrimeLoop n i
    | i == n = True
    | i == 2 = (mod n i /= 0) && isPrimeLoop n (i+1)
    | otherwise = (mod n i /= 0) && isPrimeLoop n (i+2)

isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime n = isPrimeLoop n 2

newFiniteField :: Integer -> Maybe FiniteField
newFiniteField n
    | not (isPrime n) = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just (FiniteField add addinv mul mulinv new)
    where
        add = (\x y -> FieldElement (mod (toInt x + toInt y) n) )
        addinv = (\x -> FieldElement (mod (n - toInt x) n) )
        mul = (\x y -> FieldElement (mod (toInt x * toInt y) n) )
        mulinv = (\x -> FieldElement (mod (modMulInv (toInt x) n) n) )
        new = (\x -> FieldElement x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue you have to work around is the fact that you shouldn't be allowed to add/multiply/etc. values of `FiniteField` under different orders.  The solution is pretty straightforward from a type-system perspective: give values of different orders different types.

```
newtype FieldElem (n :: Nat) = FieldElem Integer
```

`Nat` is a kind (from the GHC.TypeLits module) whose inhabitants are type-level numerical literals like `1`, `2`, `3`, etc.

So now, you have different types:

```
FieldElem 7     -- the type of an element of a finite field of order 7
FieldElem 11    -- the type of an element of a finite field of order 11
```

So if you try to add two values of different types, you get a compile error.

```
> (x :: FieldElem 7) + (y :: FieldElem 11)
Error!  You can only use + on two things of the same type!
> (x :: FieldElem 7) + (y :: FieldElem 7)
-- result: something of type FieldElem 7
```

Now you can implement the `Num` instance:

```
instance Num (FieldElem n) where
   (+) = ...
   (*) = ...
```

One issue here is that `(+)` needs to know what the order is, and the only information is in the type of `FieldElem`.  To go around this, we require `n` to be an instance of the `KnownNat` typeclass (also from GHC.TypeLits), which lets us get its integer value as a value at runtime:

```
natVal :: KnownNat n => Proxy n -> Integer
```

so,

```
> natVal (Proxy :: Proxy 10)
10
> natVal (Proxy :: Proxy 19)
19
```

And so our final design: (which requires `ScopedTypeVariables` to let us use the `n` type variable)

```
instance KnownNat n => Num (FieldElem n) where
  FieldElem x + FieldElem y = FieldElem (mod (x + y) n)
    where
      n = natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)
```

etc.!

You can bring in `Integer`s into `FieldElem` using a smart constructor:

```
mkFieldElem :: forall n. KnownNat n => Integer -> Maybe (FieldElem n)
mkFieldElem x | isPrime n = Just (FieldElem (mod x n))
              | otherwise = Nothing
  where
    n = natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)
```

The nice thing is that you get to use Haskell's type inference to specify the order you want:

```
> mkFieldElem 10 :: Maybe (FieldElem 23)
Just (FieldElem 10)     -- :: Maybe (FieldElem 23)
```

Instead of manually passing it as a parameter! :)

By using smart constructors (and hiding the actual constructor) you can make sure that the user never has any values of type `FieldElem 8`, for instance, so you don't have to worry about fields of bad orders being added together.

Note that, unfortunately, `fromInteger :: KnownNat n => Integer -> FieldElem n` will necessarily be partial.  It has to reject bad orders.  But there are a large number of instances in *base* with partial implementations of `fromInteger` anyway :|  But, `fromInteger` being in `Num` is a bad idea anyways, and `Num` is a bad typeclass, so it's `Num`'s fault :)

---

**EDIT** There's a potential way to make `fromInteger` not partial/total: we could create a `Prime` typeclass and have only instances where the `Nat` parameter is prime:

```
class KnownNat n => Prime (n :: Nat)
```

Then you could make:

```
mkFieldElem :: Prime n => Integer -> FieldElem n
mkFieldElem x = FieldElem (mod x n)
  where
    n = natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)
```

And now if you had:

```
instance Prime n => Num (FieldElem n) where
  ...
  fromInteger = mkFieldElem
```

`fromInteger` would be a total function, because the only instances would be for prime order fields!

However, in order for this to work, you need to get your instances of `Prime` in a way that GHC can understand.  In theory, this could be done using a GHC type checker extension --- you could write your own type checker extension so that `n` is given a `Prime` instance if it's prime at compile-time.  However, this hasn't been done yet ... the next best thing you can do is offer run-time proofs of prime-ness:

```
witPrime :: forall n.KnownNat n => Proxy n -> Maybe (Dict (Prime n))
witPrime p | isPrime (natVal p) = Just (unsafeCoerce (Dict :: Dict (KnownNat n))
           | otherwise          = Nothing
```

This is using `Dict` from the [constraints](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.8/docs/Data-Constraint.html) library, which is one way of generating typeclass instances at runtime.  If you ever pattern match on the `Dict` constructor of a value of type `Dict c`, the instance `c` is "in scope" in that case statement.

In our case, then, we can do:

```
case witPrime (Proxy :: Proxy 11) of
  Just Dict -> ... -- in this branch, `Prime 11` is an instance we can use
  Nothing   -> ... -- here, it isn't
```

Or we can run it in GHCi:

```
> let x = mkFieldElem 6 :: FieldElem 11
Error: No instance for (Prime 11)
> case witPrime (Proxy :: Proxy 11) of
    Just Dict -> let x = mkFieldElem 6 :: FieldElem 11  -- okay, because of Dict constructor match
                 in  print x
FieldElem 6    -- :: FieldElem 11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't productively use `Num` with this design.  The important thing about type classes is that dispatch is done by type, not value.  An instance of `Num` for `FieldElement` wouldn't have any way of knowing what `FiniteField` it belongs to, so its operations can't depend on what field you're operating in.

There are a couple directions you could take this that would work with `Num`.

The first is making `FieldElement` an expression type that builds up expression trees with its `Num` instance, then can be evaluated within a particular `FiniteField`.  This has the advantage of using very simple techniques.  It has the disadvantage of being *really* bad for memory and performance when the computations get complex.

The second is to follow a pattern like `Data.Fixed`.  You would change `FiniteField` to a class and implement it on some empty types representing various specific fields, with names like `F17`, for instance.  Then you parameterize `FieldElement` with a type argument that's used to mark which `FiniteField` they belong to.  Finally, the instance of `Num` for `FiniteElement` requires that its argument have a `FiniteField` instance, which is used in its implementation.  This approach has the advantage of being really nice to work with.  The disadvantage is requiring a boilerplate `FiniteField` instance for each field you want to work in.

A third option is very similar to the above, but replacing the custom `F17` like data types with some sort of type-level natural. (Either manual, or from `-XDataKinds`).  Then you can implement the `Num` instance in terms of the type-level natural.  The advantage here is that you get rid of all the boilerplate instances from the previous approach. The disadvantage is that it doesn't require that the type-level argument is a prime number, and several calculations are wrong if it isn't prime.

Comment: Is there any way to alter the design to allow me to use `Num`?

Comment: @IzaakWeiss There are a bunch of options - I covered a few of them in the edit I was working on for the last 12 or so minutes.